# Added and removed file in VisualStudio - compile errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake

My main problem is: I removed files from the ProjectMappen-Explorer (Project Explorer) and     then added them again.
Now the Project does not compile anymore and i cannot find out why.

How can I make it compile again?

The Project was generated by cmake and this is some big overhead, too.

And: I want to add files on my own and this will lead to the same problem. So re-generating is useless.

Thank you for your help!

#### Error 1

```
Fehler  1   error MSB3073: Der Befehl "setlocal
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\ctest.exe" --force-new-ctest-process -C Debug
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" wurde mit dem Code 8 beendet.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   113 6   RUN_TESTS
```

#### Error 3

```
Fehler  3   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: bool __cdecl SolidMesh::PointInPolygonAlgorithm::pointInPolygon(class osg::Vec3f)" (?pointInPolygon@PointInPolygonAlgorithm@SolidMesh@@QEAA_NVVec3f@osg@@@Z)" in Funktion ""public: static bool __cdecl DomAdapter::PointInPolygon(class osg::Vec3f const &,class osg::ref_ptr<class osg::TemplateArray<class osg::Vec3f,10,3,5126> > const &)" (?PointInPolygon@DomAdapter@@SA_NAEBVVec3f@osg@@AEBV?$ref_ptr@V?$TemplateArray@VVec3f@osg@@$09$02$0BEAG@@osg@@@3@@Z)".   C:\Users\wollknaeul\Documents\HPI\algorithmische geometrie\algogeometrie\trunk\build\algorithmtest\PointInPolygonTest.obj   test_Algorithm
```

#### Error 4

```
Fehler  2   error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code 9009 beendet.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   151 6   run
```

#### Answer to Questions

```
in>"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\ctest.exe" --force-new-ctest-process -C
 Debug
Test project C:/Users/wollknaeul/Documents/HPI/algorithmische geometrie/algogeom
etrie/trunk/bin
    Start 1: test_Algorithm
Could not find executable test_Algorithm
Looked in the following places:
test_Algorithm
test_Algorithm.exe
Debug/test_Algorithm
Debug/test_Algorithm.exe
Debug/test_Algorithm
Debug/test_Algorithm.exe
Unable to find executable: test_Algorithm
1/1 Test #1: test_Algorithm ...................***Not Run   0.00 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.11 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - test_Algorithm (Not Run)
Errors while running CTest
```

Comment: **Error 1** I was getting this when CMake did not have privileges to install a file in the install folder. Are you running Visual Studio with Administrator Privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Right click on *Project* -> *Rebuild* or *Build again*. "Neu Erstellen"

---

**Error 1**

Your first error is MSB3073 and sounds like a pre or post build issue, specifically some sort of error from a script running on your pre or post build event.

(Translating from German via translate.google.com):

> The command "setlocal "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\ctest.exe"
>   --force-new-ctest-process -C Debug if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd :cmEnd endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
>   :cmErrorLevel exit /b %1 :cmDone if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
>   :VCEnd" exited with Code 8. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 113 6
>   RUN_TESTS

Are you able to run these scripts from a batch file?

**Error 3 (2?)**

Your second (third?) error is
   [LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Error 4**

Google has a bunch of stuff about your last error [MSB6006](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=MSB6006)

Comment: I just added and removed a file in the manager - it did not change the files on the disk. I try running it.

Comment: @user1320237 Do you mind marking it as the answer then? It looks like the error was in your pre/post build script. At least that's what it sounds like from your update.

Comment: someone came by and helped me so this is not the answer... I will write the answer above but than you.

Comment: I moved the answer from the question to here. Answers should not be written in questions on SO.

Comment: I am getting a similar error, 
error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd returned 1

And it is not solved by running VS as admin and I see nothing wrong with the cmake file. Anyone found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Run Visual Studio in Administrator privileges. The error is basically that CMake can not access the C:/Program Files (x86) directory to create/add the necessary files.